# Error llamando a una función javascript: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Hola he copiado este código de una página que desarrolla un paginador y le he implementado un `slider` de números, en dichos números quiero llamar a la funcion `showSlide` (número) para cargar una pregunta N de el quiz

El caso es que no me deja recoger ninguna función, porque implementa los eventos de una manera muy específica, filtra los elementos `dom` por elements by id, y les añade el evento;

```
// display quiz right away

  const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");

  const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");


  showSlide(0);

  // on submit, show results

  submitButton.addEventListener("click", showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para llamar a la función desde el html en onclick generado para llamar a la variable del bucle incrementada i sin usar estos objetos y que no me de error ?

Aquí dejo el resto del codigo

```js
(function() {
  const myQuestions = [{
      question: "Who is the strongest?",
      answers: {
        a: "Superman",
        b: "The Terminator",
        c: "Waluigi, obviously"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "What is the best site ever created?",
      answers: {
        a: "SitePoint",
        b: "Simple Steps Code",
        c: "Trick question; they're both the best"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "Where is Waldo really?",
      answers: {
        a: "Antarctica",
        b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
        c: "Sitting in a tree",
        d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
      },
      correctAnswer: "d"
    }
  ];



  function buildQuiz() {
    // we'll need a place to store the HTML output
    const output = [];
    var questionNumber = 0;
    // for each question...
    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
      // we'll want to store the list of answer choices
      const answers = [];

      // and for each available answer...
      for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
        // ...add an HTML radio button
        answers.push(
          `<label>
             <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
              ${letter} :
              ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
           </label>`
        );
      }

      // add this question and its answers to the output
      output.push(
        `<div class="slide">
           <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
           <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
         </div>`
      );
    });

    // finally combine our output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");



  }

  function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
  }

  function showResults() {
    // gather answer containers from our quiz
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll(".answers");

    // keep track of user's answers
    let numCorrect = 0;

    // for each question...
    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
      // find selected answer
      const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
      const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
      const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;
      var cadenaRespuestas = "";
      // if answer is correct
      var respuesta = "";
      if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
        // add to the number of correct answers
        respuesta = "correcta";
        numCorrect++;

        // color the answers green
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "lightgreen";
      } else {
        // if answer is wrong or blank
        // color the answers red
        respuesta = "incorrecta";
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "red";
      }
      cadenaRespuestas += answerContainer.cuestion + "  " + respuesta;
    });
    alert(cadenaRespuestas);
    // show number of correct answers out of total
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} out of ${myQuestions.length}`;
  }

  function pintaSlide() {
    //  alert(total+"  "+actual);
    var liprev = document.getElementById("slider").childNodes[1];

    var cadena = "";

    for (i = slides.length; i > 0; i--) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      slider = [];
      if (i <= 0) {
        li.innerHTML = "<li id='numpag" + (i - 1) + "'><a onclick='showSlide2(" + i + ");' class='active'>1</a></li>";

      } else {
        li.innerHTML = "<li id='numpag" + (i - 1) + "' > <a onclick='showSlide2(" + i + ");' >" + i + "</a></li>";

      }
      insertAfter(li, liprev);
    }



    // deslizador.innerHTML=paginador+cadena+finpag;

  }

  function showSlide(n) {


    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("active-slide");
    slides[n].classList.add("active-slide");
    currentSlide = n;

    if (currentSlide === 0) {
      previousButton2.style.display = "none";
      previousButton.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      previousButton2.style.display = "inline-block";
      previousButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    }

    if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) {
      nextButton.style.display = "none";
      nextButton2.style.display = "none";
      submitButton.style.display = "inline-block";

    } else {
      nextButton2.style.display = "inline-block";
      nextButton.style.display = "inline-block";
      submitButton.style.display = "none";
    }




    if (currentSlide < slides.length) {
      slides[currentSlide].classList.add("active-slide");
      document.getElementById("previous").classList.add("active-slide");
      lia = document.getElementById("numpag" + currentSlide);
      if (lia != null) {
        lia.classList.add("active");
      }
      // paginasNum.classList.add("active");
    }

  }

  function showNextSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
  }

  function showPreviousSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }

  function showNextSlide2() {
    showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
  }

  function showPreviousSlide2() {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }

  function showslide2(n) {
    showSlide(n);
  }
  const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
  const resultsContainer = document.getElementById("results");
  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

  // display quiz right away
  buildQuiz();

  const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
  const previousButton2 = document.getElementById("previous2");
  const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
  const nextButton2 = document.getElementById("next2");
  const liActiva = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("li");
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  lia = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("li");
  let currentSlide = 0;

  showSlide(0);
  pintaSlide();
  // on submit, show results
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
  previousButton2.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide2);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);

  nextButton2.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide2);
})();
```

```html
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./estilos1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <h1>Quiz on Important Facts</h1>
  <div id="pagination">
    <ul id="slider" class="pagination modal-3">
      <li><a href="#" id="previous" class="prev">&laquo</a></li>


      <li><a href="#" id="next" class="next">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul><br>

  </div>
  <div class="quiz-container">
    <ul class="pagination modal-3"></ul>

      <div id="quiz"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="previous2">Previous Question</button>
  <button id="next2">Next Question</button>
  <button id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
  <div id="results"></div>




</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución final era borrar los objetos que llamaban a la función, una vez los borré ya podía llamar a la función desde html en cualquier elemento, un saludo gracias

```
/*
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
  previousButton2.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide2);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);

  nextButton2.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide2);
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Veamos, en tu código hay un pequeño lío con las variables globales (las que defines como const) y las funciones dentro del `function()`.

El `function()` del principio denota que necesitas la librería jQuery, ya que dicho código es la manera corta de escribir `$( document ).ready()`

Te he añadido la librería jQuery en el snipplet.

Además te he sacado fuera del `function()` las funciones que tienes definidas, además de las definiciones de las variables, que al ser globales deben de estar también fuera del `function()`.

Dentro del `function()` realmente debe de estar sólo el código JS que llame al resto de funciones que te definas fuera del `function()`. Dicho código se ejecutará sólo una vez cuando el navegador termine de cargar el DOM.

Con este cambio el código funciona aunque da algunos errores de desplazamiento en el array slides, imagino que por no calcular correctamente los índices en tu código, pero por lo menos ya se ve un poco como se navega entre los elementos.

```js
const myQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the strongest?",
    answers: {
      a: "Superman",
      b: "The Terminator",
      c: "Waluigi, obviously"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "What is the best site ever created?",
    answers: {
      a: "SitePoint",
      b: "Simple Steps Code",
      c: "Trick question; they're both the best"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "Where is Waldo really?",
    answers: {
      a: "Antarctica",
      b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
      c: "Sitting in a tree",
      d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
    },
    correctAnswer: "d"
  }
];



function buildQuiz() {
  // we'll need a place to store the HTML output
  const output = [];
  var questionNumber = 0;
  // for each question...
  myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
    // we'll want to store the list of answer choices
    const answers = [];

    // and for each available answer...
    for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
      // ...add an HTML radio button
      answers.push(
        `<label>
             <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
              ${letter} :
              ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
           </label>`
      );
    }

    // add this question and its answers to the output
    output.push(
      `<div class="slide">
           <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
           <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
         </div>`
    );
  });

  // finally combine our output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
  quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");

}

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function showResults() {
  // gather answer containers from our quiz
  const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll(".answers");

  // keep track of user's answers
  let numCorrect = 0;

  // for each question...
  myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
    // find selected answer
    const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
    const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
    const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;
    var cadenaRespuestas = "";
    // if answer is correct
    var respuesta = "";
    if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
      // add to the number of correct answers
      respuesta = "correcta";
      numCorrect++;

      // color the answers green
      answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "lightgreen";
    } else {
      // if answer is wrong or blank
      // color the answers red
      respuesta = "incorrecta";
      answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "red";
    }
    cadenaRespuestas += answerContainer.cuestion + "  " + respuesta;
  });
  alert(cadenaRespuestas);
  // show number of correct answers out of total
  resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} out of ${myQuestions.length}`;
}

function pintaSlide() {
  //  alert(total+"  "+actual);
  var liprev = document.getElementById("slider").childNodes[1];

  var cadena = "";

  for (i = slides.length; i > 0; i--) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    slider = [];
    if (i <= 0) {
      li.innerHTML = "<li id='numpag" + (i - 1) + "'><a onclick='showSlide2(" + i + ");' class='active'>1</a></li>";

    } else {
      li.innerHTML = "<li id='numpag" + (i - 1) + "' > <a onclick='showSlide2(" + i + ");' >" + i + "</a></li>";

    }
    insertAfter(li, liprev);
  }



  // deslizador.innerHTML=paginador+cadena+finpag;

}

function showSlide(n) {


  slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("active-slide");
  slides[n].classList.add("active-slide");
  currentSlide = n;

  if (currentSlide === 0) {
    previousButton2.style.display = "none";
    previousButton.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    previousButton2.style.display = "inline-block";
    previousButton.style.display = "inline-block";
  }

  if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) {
    nextButton.style.display = "none";
    nextButton2.style.display = "none";
    submitButton.style.display = "inline-block";

  } else {
    nextButton2.style.display = "inline-block";
    nextButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    submitButton.style.display = "none";
  }




  if (currentSlide < slides.length) {
    slides[currentSlide].classList.add("active-slide");
    document.getElementById("previous").classList.add("active-slide");
    lia = document.getElementById("numpag" + currentSlide);
    if (lia != null) {
      lia.classList.add("active");
    }
    // paginasNum.classList.add("active");
  }

}

function showSlide2(n) {
  showSlide(n);
}

function showNextSlide() {
  showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function showPreviousSlide() {
  showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

function showNextSlide2() {
  showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function showPreviousSlide2() {
  showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

var quizContainer;
var resultsContainer;
var submitButton;
var previousButton;
var previousButton2;
var nextButton;
var nextButton2;
var liActiva;
var slides = new Array();
var currentSlide;

(function() {

  quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
  resultsContainer = document.getElementById("results");
  submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

  // display quiz right away
  buildQuiz();

  previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
  previousButton2 = document.getElementById("previous2");
  nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
  nextButton2 = document.getElementById("next2");
  liActiva = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("li");
  slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  lia = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("li");
  currentSlide = 0;

  showSlide(0);
  pintaSlide();
  // on submit, show results
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
  previousButton2.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide2);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);

  nextButton2.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide2);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./estilos1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <h1>Quiz on Important Facts</h1>
  <div id="pagination">
    <ul id="slider" class="pagination modal-3">
      <li><a href="#" id="previous" class="prev">&laquo</a></li>


      <li><a href="#" id="next" class="next">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul><br>

  </div>
  <div class="quiz-container">
    <ul class="pagination modal-3"></ul>

    <div id="quiz"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="previous2">Previous Question</button>
  <button id="next2">Next Question</button>
  <button id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
  <div id="results"></div>




</body>
```